# Special case Counting of Records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been asked to provide a report that counts the types of land. The problem is if the parcel in question has multiples types of land, then the count is to go to the portion of land that has the largest market and ignoring the reset. The tables help show what I am working with and then the desired output.

```
    TRMaster Table
Year  Parcel   District
2012  0-0-12   1
2012  0-0-15   1
2012  0-0-20   3

TRValue Table
Year Parcel    PropCode    Market
2012  0-0-12      LC01     10,000
2012  0-0-12      LR01     25,000
2012  0-0-15      LA01     30,000
2012  0-0-15      LS01     28,000
2012  0-0-20      LR01     13,000
2012  0-0-20      LS01     15,000
2012  0-0-20      LS02     18,000

TRProp Table
PropCode    tc233    PropType
LA01           1         A
LC02           3         A
LR01           2         A
LS01           4         A
LS02           4

Desired Output
District tc233    Count
1         1        1    (from 0-0-15 LA01)
1         2        1    (from 0-0-12 LR01)
3         4        1    (from 0-0-20 LS02)
```

The following query is close, but does not work because of the MIN clause on p.tc233. It returns, of course, the minimum p.tc233 value for each of the set of records for a parcel in TRValue!

```
Select  m.District, MIN(p.tc233), MAX(v1.currentmarket), COUNT(*)
  from trvalue v
 inner join TRProp P on 
       p.code = v.Code and p.PropType = 'A'
 inner join TRMaster m on 
       m.Year = v.Year and m.Parcel = v.parcel and m.Deleted = 0
 where v.Year = 2012 
 group by m.district, p.tc233
having MAX(v.currentmarket) > 0
 order by m.district, p.tc233
```

I am thinking a sub-select or two will be necessary! If more  info is need, please ask and I will provide what I can.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This gives your required result, but I'm not sure it's entirely correct:

```
;With RatedMarkets as (
   select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parcel ORDER BY Market desc) as rn
  from TRValue
)
select
  m.District,
  p.tc233,
  COUNT(*)
from
  TRMaster m
    inner join
  RatedMarkets rm
    on
      m.Parcel = rm.Parcel and
      rm.rn = 1
    inner join
  TRProp p
    on
      rm.PropCode = p.PropCode
group by
  m.District,p.tc233
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b075e/3)

Comment: Your solution was excellent! I only had to make some minor tweaks for some additional filtering and it is working. Thank-you for time and effort.